# Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

in the request payload if i pass files and having Laravel Validation for file type, it shows error `Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed` always even validation error is different, suppose having validation like below

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'request_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:client_requests,id'],
            'client_name' => ['required'],
            'discussion_date_time' => ['sometimes', 'date_format:d/m/Y h:i A'],
            'additional_comments' => ['required'],
            'images'       => ['sometimes'],
            'images.*'     => ['sometimes', 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/heic', 'max:200000'],
        ];
    }
```

If there is an error of lets say "client_name", it will not show like "Client name field is required", it will show 500 with `"Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed"`

Below is the `stacktrace`

```
[2022-12-26 06:53:47] local.ERROR: Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed {"userId":528,"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile' is not allowed at /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:158)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(158): serialize()
#1 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(127): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createObjectPayload()
#2 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(105): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayloadArray()
#3 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(126): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayload()
#4 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(71): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->later()
#5 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(573): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->laterOn()
#6 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(498): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->queueHandler()
#7 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(424): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(249): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(450): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#10 /var/www/html/projects/api/app/Http/Controllers/CustomExceptions.php(68): event()
#11 /var/www/html/projects/api/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(261): App\\Http\\Controllers\\CustomExceptions::sendEmail()
#12 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(337): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->App\\Exceptions\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render()
#14 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException()
#15 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#17 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#19 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#20 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#21 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#23 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(34): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#27 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->handle()
#28 /var/www/html/projects/api/app/Http/Middleware/PlatformCheck.php(48): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): App\\Http\\Middleware\\PlatformCheck->handle()
#30 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#32 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#33 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#34 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#35 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#36 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#39 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#41 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#42 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#44 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#45 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#47 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#48 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#49 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#50 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#51 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#52 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#53 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#54 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#55 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#56 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#58 /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#59 /var/www/html/projects/api/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#60 /var/www/html/projects/api/server.php(18): require_once('/var/www/html/p...')
#61 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Are you using  laravel's default `form validation` or your custom logic?

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli I am using lraravel's default form validation

Comment: Your Problem might be in another piece of code. Stow the entire stacktrace of the laravel.log

Comment: @UnderDog

[2022-12-23 13:33:59] local.ERROR: Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed {"userId":568,"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile' is not allowed at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:158)

Comment: 1) Open storage/logs/laravel.log  2) copy the entire log  3) paste it in your original question. We need to see FULL error, not just a tiny bit. Under your error in the log is something that's called a stacktrace with lots of numbers and lots of files. It needs to be in your original question. You have more room to paste stuff there. You're allowed to edit your original question

Comment: @UnderDog - stacktrace has been added

Comment: Bingo! Great job on posting the stacktrace. See this line? `App\\Http\\Controllers\\CustomExceptions::sendEmail()` can you paste the contents of the entire function? You're sending an email after an exception occurred, which is fine, but let's see the contents of that function first

Comment: After that, see this line? `api/app/Http/Controllers/CustomExceptions.php(68)` you are dispatching an event, which is fine. You'll see that once you've pasted that sendMail() function. The contents of the event, we need to see that as well

Comment: @UnderDog, You are awesome, i just comment that Event code api/app/Http/Controllers/CustomExceptions.php(68) and it worked, now showing actual validation error, but not sure why due to that event calling code is causing issue,

Comment: event(new AdministratorEmailEvent($emailData)); is the code inside App\\Http\\Controllers\\CustomExceptions::sendEmail()

Comment: Ok, but always try to update your original question. Reading these updates inside these tiny comments is not optimal.  As soon as you find something, like that update, don't wait till we ask: "show the contents of AdministratorEmailEvent". Just update your original question. Now, 2 things: 1) dd($emailData) and ... you guessed it, `show the contents of AdministratorEmailEvent` in your original question please

Comment: @UnderDog somehow due to that event calling code, i am showing that error message instead of actual validation message, you can add your answer and i will make it as correct answer, thank you so much